# Replace column values between two dataframes according to index

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe named calls, each call is recorded by a date (calls)[datetime]. each call has an answer status (calls)[Status].

```
a =  {'datetime':['2021-11-22 18:47:02','2021-01-08 14:18:11','2021-06-08 16:40:45','2021-12-03 10:21:31','2021-12-03 15:21:31'], 
      'Status': ['P_TR_SOK', 'RS_GEN', 'P_TR_ST_','RS_GEN', 'MLR_ST']}

calls = pd.DataFrame(data = a)
```

A second Dataframe named NewStatus with same column (`NewStatus`)[datetime] and the column (`NewStatus`)[New_Status] that I want to replace in the first dataframe with a date join

```
b = {'datetime': ['2021-11-22 18:47:02','2021-01-08 14:18:11','2021-06-08 16:40:45','2021-12-03 10:21:31'], 
     'New_Status': ['AB_CL_NO','REP','AB_AUT','DROP']}

NewStatus = pd.DataFrame(data = b)
```

Desired result is the following for calls :

| datetime | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-22 18:47:02 | AB_CL_NO |
| 2021-01-08 14:18:11 | REP |
| 2021-06-08 16:40:45 | AB_AUT |
| 2021-12-03 10:21:31 | DROP |
| 2021-12-03 15:21:31 | MLR_ST |

By using

```
calls.reset_index().set_index('datetime').join(NewStatus.drop_duplicates().set_index('datetime'), how='left', rsuffix='df2')
```

I am blocked how to replace the old Status by making the join with "datetime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

**UPDATE**
Be aware that [`pd.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) works `inplace`.

```
calls= calls.set_index('datetime')
calls.update(NewStatus.set_index('datetime').rename(columns={'New_Status': 'Status'}))
print(calls)

                       Status
datetime                     
2021-11-22 18:47:02  AB_CL_NO
2021-01-08 14:18:11       REP
2021-06-08 16:40:45    AB_AUT
2021-12-03 10:21:31      DROP
2021-12-03 15:21:31    MLR_ST
```

*Old answer*

```
calls= calls.set_index('datetime')
out = (calls.join(NewStatus.drop_duplicates()
                  .set_index('datetime')
                  .rename(columns={'New_Status':'Status'}), how='left', rsuffix='_updated')
       .rename(columns={'Status_updated': 'Replaced_Status'})
       .drop('Status', axis=1)
       .dropna())
print(out)

                    Replaced_Status
datetime                           
2021-11-22 18:47:02        AB_CL_NO
2021-01-08 14:18:11             REP
2021-06-08 16:40:45          AB_AUT
2021-12-03 10:21:31            DROP
```

Comment: Thank's @Rabinzel but the join only works for equivalent values; for example the last row : |   2021-12-03 15:21:31|  MLR_ST

Comment: did you update your expexted result or did I missed that? I thought that's what you want. Is it ok for you to change the `calls` df or do you need a new df?

Comment: yes change `calls` by replacing `Status` ; yes I had forgotten this detail

Comment: ok, I'll have a look and update my answer then

Comment: Please have a look. I updated my answer.